# iOS file system: adding/removing/sorting files

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, filesystems

I have a directory with images like this:

```
0000.png
0001.png
0002.png
0003.png
etc...
```

To add an image, I query the count of the directory and name the new file with the count. I need to maintain such an order because these images are eventually displayed in a grid view. This is the easy part. What is bugging me is manipulating the directory later.

The user can delete and reorder these as they wish. So how should I handle reordering of the actual directory?

I have tried, naively, copying the images into an NSMutableArray, loading those into the gridView, letting the user manipulate, then upon finish I wipe the directory and rewrite the images. That's fine for a few images, but there can be many and it slowly builds up.

I like the idea of copying the images locally, manipulating and then fixing the directory. But I think there has got to be a better way to manage the directory instead of wiping and rewriting, would it be faster to write some kind of file-swapping method?

Comment: Just rename (move) each of the files. The trick is renaming in the right order to avoid name collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the images to the file system in an ordered format, you could have a meta data file images.plist
And maintain an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionaries`
Each dictionary will contain the data for the imageFile Path and the image index
Then when you would save the changes of the user you will only rewrite this plist file, instead of saving all the images again

Comment: Oh wow this is an interesting approach, I'll give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid writing images to disk frequently, instead use pointers to image files and keep the arrangment of the image in a smaller metadata file (or even an SQL DB) since accessing and modifying these structure is hundreds of time easier and consume much less memory and RAM